# Compilation error when linking global array of structs

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to define an array of structs in `somedriver_cardSpecific.c`, declare it in `somedriver.h`, then use it in `somedriver.c`. But I get a compilation error in `somedriver.c`:

```
error: array '__mod_i2c__somedriver_idtable_device_table' assumed to have one element [-Werror]
 extern const typeof(name) __mod_##type##__##name##_device_table

in expansion of macro 'MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE'
 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, somedriver_idtable);
```

Here are the relevant bits of code:

**somedriver_cardSpecific.c**

```
#include <linux/i2c.h>

#include "somedriver.h"

struct i2c_device_id somedriver_idtable[] = {
    { "somedevice_1",   0 },
    { "somedevice_2",   1 },
    { },
};
```

**somedriver.h**

```
#include <linux/i2c.h>

extern struct i2c_device_id somedriver_idtable[];
```

**somedriver.c**

```
#include "somedriver.h"

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, somedriver_idtable);
```

Not sure why I'm getting that compilation error. Am I doing this linkage wrong: does the definition of somedriver_idtable need a definite size? or is it a constraint of the `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` macro?

If you're wondering why in this Linux device driver I'm separating the i2c_device_id table from the MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE: I'm trying to re-factor the code so later boards that have different amounts of i2c devices can just create their own somedriver_cardSpecific.c file and compile/link that.

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT:**
The macro is defined in Linux kernel: linux/module.h.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h#L212

```
210 #ifdef MODULE
211 /* Creates an alias so file2alias.c can find device table. */
212 #define MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(type, name)                                 \
213 extern const typeof(name) __mod_##type##__##name##_device_table         \
214   __attribute__ ((unused, alias(__stringify(name))))
215 #else  /* !MODULE */
216 #define MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(type, name)
217 #endif
```

Comment: Please post the macro.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie posted in edit. It's here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h#L210

Comment: it looks like somedriver_cardSpecifc.o is not being linked. The linker can see the extern [] but not the concrete implemenation

Comment: Should the last call read `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, somedriver_idtable);`?

Comment: @PeterK Oops, yes your are correct :). Sorry trying to not post real device name.

Comment: What happens if you make it `const`?

Comment: I guess it needs the length of the original array in order to make the alias.

Comment: Why not just put the `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` in the card-specific file?

Comment: Probably you can also just ignore the warning, it should still place the alias correctly.

Comment: @PeterK The `__mod_i2c__somedriver_idtable_device_table` alias in the symbol table would describe an object at the correct address, but with the wrong size, which might cause problems for the module tools.

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't think this would be a problem, because the end of the array is detected when an element with a null device name is reached, which is why the last element is an empty struct. But nonetheless it'd be better & cleaner to make the warning go away than just ignoring it.

Comment: @IanAbbott. Making it const didn't help. As for putting MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE in the same .c as the struct array, I tried that but it didn't help either. The reason I think is just by having the somedriver_idtable as a global causes the Macro to fail. I need to have it as global because it's used in somedriver.c as well for other stuff.

Comment: @IanAbbott  With the MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE in the same .c as the struct array looks to be working now on a clean build. So I take back what I said before. Still confused as to how and why though so I'll try a few more things and post what really ended up working. Thanks Ian, Peter and Fabio.

Comment: The `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE` doesn't necessarily need to be in the same .c file as the table, but it needs to know the size of the table, and it cannot determine that from your current `extern` declaration. You could add the array length to the `extern` declaration, but you'd have to change it every time you add or remove an entry in the table, which may be a maintenance nightmare. Since it doesn't really matter which .c file contains the `MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE`, putting it in the same file as the actual table is the most maintainer-friendly option.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for the tip! So your suggestion works and is what I ended up going with. I'll post what I ended doing as the answer (sorry I forgot to do this before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

1. I cleaned the build directory. Building on top of old builds caused failures with these files, not sure why.
2. As @IanAbbott mentioned, I moved the MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE() macro to be within the same file as the i2c_device_id table definition. As Ian and Fabio mentioned the macro needs to see the size of the table and cannot see that with just the extern. I didn't want to have future coders needing to define the size with every new board so I chose to keep them together. Here's how that will look:

**somedriver_cardSpecific.c**

```
#include <linux/module.h>    
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include "somedriver.h"

struct i2c_device_id somedriver_idtable[] = {
    { "somedevice_1",   0 },
    { "somedevice_2",   1 },
    { },
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, somedriver_idtable);
```

**somedriver.h**

```
#include <linux/i2c.h>

extern struct i2c_device_id somedriver_idtable[];
```

Driver still works fine. I hope that helps someone who comes across same problem.

Comment: Okay. Ideally, it should be declared `const` though.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error just because you have the flag to treat all warnings as errors on. One way to solve that would be to disable such flag, but I'd recommend as a better approach to declare explicitly the array size [3] both in the header and in the .c, this should make the warning go away and the error with it.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I tried to declare the array size explicity in both .c and .h. It solves the original error "assumed to have one element", but now has a differnt error: "error: '__mod_i2c__somedriver_idtable_device_table' aliased to undefined symbol 'somedriver_idtable'"

Comment: Hmm I just did a clean build and now it's compiling fine. I'll take back what I said and try a few more things. Thanks Fabio.